# print the character in the string with the lowest Unicode

Tags: java

I am trying to learn java but I am lost with the challenge below

what it does:
0. prompt user for a String
1. read a String from the user
2. print the character in the string with the lowest Unicode
3. continue until the user enters the string 0
Example:
enter a string (end with 0): ksjdhfasksjsh
first: a
enter a string (end with 0): ksdjdhfgKKFHDFGASDJSDHsjsdhjasjhdsj
first: A

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Set a `char` variable `min` to Integer.MAX_VALUE;
- iterate thru the String and get each character
- Compare to min. If less than min assign char to min
- when done the min value will be the lowest value character
- so print it.